# Are the WotC archives of d20 Character Optimization forum forever lost?

Tags: dnd-3.5e, online-resources, wizards-of-the-coast

I was looking for the Wizard Handbook but all the links were broken.

Somewhere on the handbooks of other classes (on other forums) I saw a

> This was archived by WotC, here's the link

But the link leads to the welcome page of WotC (since it's broken).

Is there a way to get all that info back? Do you know where to get it from? The Wayback Machine did not archive the forums.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

**Mostly not**

I believe most of the forum has migrated to the [Previous Editions Character Optimization subforum](http://community.wizards.com/go/forum/view/75882/136042/d20_Character_Optimization), with the unfortunate requirement of most links being broken. A search on thread topic in Google may be more profitable though.

However, all is not lost. There are two repositories of handbook indexes (of varying freshness and duplication state -- I generally search all of them):

- [Brilliant Gameologists - Handbook Index](http://brilliantgameologists.com/boards/index.php?topic=12678.0)
- [Min/max boards - Handbook Index](http://www.minmaxforum.com/index.php?topic=399.0)

These two lexicons (I believe BG is more "alive") are near-complete duplications of the data (if not all of the formatting) of the old 3.5 charop boards from the wotc index, plus whatever new research the authors have felt like contributing.

The canonical wizard handbooks are:

- [Treantmonk's Guide to Wizards: Being a God](http://minmaxforum.com/index.php?topic=1570)
- [Being Batman: the Logic Ninja's Guide to Wizards](http://www.minmaxforum.com/index.php?topic=2716)

Answer (score 1):

Delving through the depths of the IAWM, I discovered that [this](http://community.wizards.com/go/forum/view/75882/136042/d20_Character_Optimization) appear to be a live site. Hopefully it is what you are looking for.

Comment: Their inner links are 85% dead, but ty anyway!

Comment: darn, it was worth a shot.

Answer (score 1):

I have good news for you! [The Wizard's Handbook](http://www.dandwiki.com/wiki/Wizards%27_Handbook_by_Dictum_Mortuum_(3.5e_Optimized_Character_Build)) is alive in the D&D Wiki!

You can find some other build from the *Character Optimization Handbook* [in the same Wiki](http://www.dandwiki.com/wiki/3.5e_Optimized_Character_Builds), merged with the builds of other users of the Wiki.