# Where can I find a good [MyClass] Handbook CharOp List?

Tags: dnd-3.5e

I want to find the most concise and clean list of CharOp **ordered by base-class**, **and not by build ideas**.

If you take a look at brilliantgameologists forum the list is a bit messy and hard to find what you are looking for.

And some have broken links, eg WotC (*Look at [this](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/q/9035/1630) question*). Has someone put it together yet?

Or should I get in motion and put it together myself?

Answer (score 1):

[**This**](http://community.wizards.com/go/thread/view/75882/19860942/Character_Optimization_Board_3.5_Build_FAQ?post_id=338100674#338100674) page on the wizard forums has CharOp information broken down by class. The links in the top post don't work (at least on my mobile device) but each class is contained within that thread, just scroll down.